# Why this combo box look like this?

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using Django smart selects. When the page loads, the combo looks like an error, if I remove `jQuery` it looks normal but the smart select won't work.

How can I revolve this?

When the page loads the combo looks like this:

[image]

But when I select an option the mark gets removed:

[image]

The code of my template

```
<form method="post">

{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}" >
<label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
{% render_field field class="form-control" %}
{% for error in field.errors %}
  <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<button class="btn btn-default">Registrar</button>
</form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        var chainfield = "#id_continent";
        var url = "/chaining/filter/backend/Country/continent/backend    /Location/country";
        var id = "#id_country";
        var value = undefined;
        var auto_choose = true;
        var empty_label = "---------";

        $(document).ready(function() {
            chainedfk.init(chainfield, url, id, value, empty_label, auto_choose);
        });
    })(jQuery || django.jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you post your actual code instead of just an image? Even better would be an example reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem put this in my model

```
blank=True
```

I need to read more in Django Docs